# Why the list in my service being destroyed?

Tags: android, android-service

I have an app with a main Activity.  I add data into a list in a service using a binder.  At the same time, I start the service which runs in the background.  When I close and restart the app, my list of data in the service is destroyed. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your service was killed and if You used [START_STICKY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) it was just restarted without any parameters (as standalone service). I think you should somehow persist information that service was invoked with parameter and save it e.g. to the database. When service finishes dealing with your data, delete that information and allow it to be invoked once again.

> Because it is in the started state, it will guarantee to call
>   onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) after creating the new service
>   instance; if there are not any **pending** start commands to be delivered
>   to the service, **it will be called with a null intent object**, so you
>   must take care to check for this.

Answer (score 0):

When you bind to a `Service`, the lifecycle of the `Service` is depending on the one that does the bind (in your case the `Activity`). So if you do a unbind in `onPause`/`onStop` the `Service` will be destroyed.

If you start the `Service` using `START_STICKY` it will be alive until stopped by user in code or by `Android OS` (when it needs resources.

(Depending what you really need), I would suggest is store it in SharedPreferences or in an other way (e.g. `SQLite` DB). To prevent losing data when something kills or stops the `Service`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally your service is not destroyed every time, but if other application needs more resources and device doesn't have it, OS can stop you app.